# Why doesn't BD139 act as a switch like my 2N3904?

Tags: transistors

I got this low power transistor that I want to make a class-A amplifier out of, but I'm having a really hard time with it. It seems not to behave much like what I expect from a transistor.

The transistor came in a TO-126 package. I've never seen one like it, so I had no idea which side was the emitter. To figure this out, I tried to build a switching circuit.

Here's the test circuit I built:
[image]

When I unplug the base resistor going to the Vcc (+12 V), I expect Q1 to stop conducting. It doesn't though. I thought maybe I messed up the orientation. Flipping it around, however, did nothing. It does not matter how I wire it.

I replaced it with a 2N3904, and that worked just as I expected. The LED starts off not being lit. Then I hit the NO switch, and it lights up. But in the circuit above, it doesn't matter what I do, the circuit is always on.

What gives guys? Why can't I use this transistor as a switch?

Comment: You know, the BD139 has his base terminal on the right side, not in the middle.

Comment: Please, type **BD139 datasheet** into your favourite search engine and read that very first PDF document it offers: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00001225.pdf

Comment: It's embarrassing... I did read that datasheet. Many times. Each time I went on to check which side the emitter was on, but I assumed that the base followed right after.... I cannot believe I was this blind.

Comment: I rolled back the weirdish "answer". Also upvoted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with 2n3904 because it has the following pinout.

[image]

But the pinout of the BD139 is not the same.

[image]

So you have to change the breadboard connections.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the datasheets for the two transistors.  The [BD139](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00001225.pdf) and the [2N3904](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3903-D.PDF) have different pinouts, that simply reversing the device does not fix.

Answer (score 0):

[image: I think this is the best picture you can find.]

I think this is the best picture you can find for the BD139